# Catching invalid xml error-message

Tags: xml, biztalk

I want to know if there is a way of catching xml that is not
valid in the Biztalk orchestration.

My orchestration brings xml in, transforms it to another format , stores it in the db and Sends an acknowledgement to the sender...

Plz Help!

Answer (score 1):

All (Xml) messages entering your BizTalk system should be validated in the receive location resulting in a NACK response to the sender if validation fails.

To **validate the structure**, you need to define a schema for your incoming Xml message and add it to the `DocumentSpecNames` property of the Xml Receive Pipeline configuration in your receive location.

However if you need to **validate the content** of your incoming messages you should use Business Rules (BRE) just after the message enter your orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at Biztalk, but you want to take a look at [XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp). It is a mean by which you can put building constraints on XML documents. If you have access to some biztalk XLD's, you can convert them into XSDs. I don't know whether Biztalk XSD's or XLD's are available. If not, you could may be create them yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more details for your specific problem?  Are the messages you're looking to validate the original message that starts the orchestration, or are the messages created within the orchestration?

Are you doing anything other than transforation, sending the data to the db, and sending an ack?  If not, I would suggest not using an orchestration at all.  All of those can be handled with maps and send port subscriptions.  Also, by adding a pipeline to your receive location, you will get the XML schema validation you are looking for.

If an orchestration is necesary, then you can still either use a receive port inside the orchestration (kind of overkill just for schema validation, but still a possibility), or you can edit the BTSNTSvc.exe.config file as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561963%28BTS.70%29.aspx).  Editing the config file, however, may introduce some overhead, as it is a server side setting.

One other option could be to have a receive port that validates the XML, then have your orchestration subscribe just to that receive port.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The message (Invalid XML) is the first message (Input message) of the orchestration.